# Why is this decoupler attached wrong?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

Why is this decoupler attached wrong?
When I launch my ship, it's fine, but why does the engineering report say this:[image]
Any ideas?

Comment: I don't play KSP, but aren't you making it harder to answer your question when you do such heavy censoring?

Comment: Like @nolonar mentioned, it's a bit hard to see. Is your decoupler vertically flipped upside down? They can look quite similar. If you separate those parts and remove the decoupler, try adding a new one from the parts page for the default orientation.

Comment: Are you sure that's the decoupler mentioned n the engineer's report?

Comment: Yes, it's red when I point to it

Comment: And I cut it out because you might think it was a different decoupler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That message is based on the location of your decoupler relative to your command pod. If you're making a lander or something, where you have two ships attached via docking ports or decouplers, that message always shows up. It's basically saying that the decoupler will separate your command pod from the part of the ship that the game things will become "debris". You can ignore it if you think you've attached your stuff correctly. It's a good warning to cause you to take a second look though.

Answer (score 0):

The hints in that window are sometimes a bit obscure, or downright wrong.
In this case, IF it's indeed the decoupler in question, it may be that the game is confused because of the struts.
It also tends to get confused when adding a radial probe core like MechJeb, warning that the probe core is attached wrong.